# How Mysql treats comparing a no string value to a indexed varchar column?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, casting

Lately I discovered a performance issue in the following use case
Before I had a table "MyTable" with a INT indexed column "MyCode"
Afterwhile Ineeded to change the table structure converting "MyCode" column to VARCHAR (index on the column was preserved)

```
 ALTER TABLE MyTable CHANGE MyCode MyCode VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL
```

Then experienced a unexpected latency, query were being performed like:

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable where MyCode = 1234
```

This query was completely ignoring the MyCode VARCHAR indexing, impression was it was full scanning the table

Converting the query to

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable where MyCode = "1234"
```

Performance get back to optimal leveraging on VARCHAR indexing

So the question is.... how to explain it... and how does actually MySQL treat indexing. Or maybe some DB setting to be changed to avoid this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int_col  = 1234      -- no problem; same type
char_col = "1234"    -- no problem; same type
int_col  = "1234"    -- string is converted to number, then no problem
char_col = 1234      -- converting all the strings to numbers -- tedious
```

In the 4th case, the index is useless, so the Optimizer looks for some other way to perform the query.  This is likely to lead to a "full table scan".

The main exception involves a "covering index", which is only slightly faster -- involving a "full *index* scan".

Comment: Thx, you're confirming my suppositions..."converting all the strings to numbers" ... so every record VARCHAR field is converted to INT to be compared to 1234? arguing why they didn't implement the opposite.... converting 1234 to string to be matched to the index....

Comment: The 3rd example is handy because it allows for simply quoting all parameter substitutions.  The 4th leads to `'1234xyz' = 1234` and `'abc' = 0`.  You can argue that this is weird or whatever, but that is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Rick James answer because he got the point.

But I'd like to add more info after having some testing.

The case in the question is: how does actually MySQL compares two values when the filtered column is varchar type and the provided value to filter by is not a string.
If this is the case you'll lose the opportunity to leverage on the index applied to the VARCHAR column having a dramatically loss of performances in your query, supposed instead to be immediate and simple.

Explanation is that MySQL in front of a given value which has a different type from 
VARCHAR will perform a full table scan and for every record's field will to perform a CAST(varcharcol as providedvaluetype) and compare the result with provided value.

E.g.

having a VARCHAR column named "code" and filtering

```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE code=1234
```

will full scan every record just like doing doing

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(code as UNSIGNED)=1234
```

Notice that if you'll test it against 0

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(code as UNSIGNED)=0
```

you'll get back ALL records having a string that its CAST to UNSIGNED won't have a unsigned meaning for mysql CAST function.